# LocalStorage values disappear when mobile device goes online

Tags: android, html, webview, local-storage

I'm trying to build a simple localStorage example using android webview. I'm having some trouble when i close the app. Everytime i start the app, values stored in localStorage disappear. I googled it and couldn't find a proper solution. Here I put my HTML, Java, Manifest code samples. Any help will be appreciated.

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function clickCounter()
{
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
  {
  if (localStorage.clickcount)
    {
    localStorage.clickcount=Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
    }
  else
    {
    localStorage.clickcount=1;
    }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="You have clicked the button " + localStorage.clickcount + " time(s).";
  }
else
  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button">Click me!</button></p>
<div id="result"></div>
<p>Click the button to see the counter increase.</p>
<p>Close the browser tab (or window), and try again, and the counter will continue to count (is not reset).</p>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVA:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDatabasePath(this.getApplicationContext().getDir("database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath());
webView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/sample.html");  
setContentView(webView);
```

MANIFEST:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Permission lines are placed under  tag but outside the  tag

and here is the scenario:
-turn off the internet connection of the mobile device
-start the app
-open the page inside the webview
-tap the button several times
-close the app (close it inside the task manager)
-turn on the internet connection of the mobile device
-start the app
-open the page
-tap button several times and it counts from beginning

you can create different scenarios while trying. The main problem is how to set the webView to use localStorage properly?There is something that i'm missing about webview.(this error does not occur when you try it on the chrome browser or any other browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a bug of webview. I was actually trying to open 3 different pages inside a webview and I was loosing localStorage data. I splitted this activity into 3 activities that each of them opens only one page. And the problem disappeared.